# RetrieveAPIView generated a error 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get an only object , I don't need an API rest full so I decided use generics.RetrieveAPIView and read the documentation of DRF, but   generated an error extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions(), AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
I dont understand why a mention appears of viewset.

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from ..models import *
from .serializers import *

class DespachoDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
  queryset = Despacho.objects.all()
  serializer_class = DespachoSerializer()
```

well here this is the routes file

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import *

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^despacho/<int:pk>', DespachoDetail.as_view(), basename='despacho-detail')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inheriting `APIView` you have to inherit a `ViewSet`.

These changes must work for you,

views.py =>

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import RetrieveModelMixin
from ..models import *
from .serializers import *

class DespachoDetail(GenericViewSet, RetrieveModelMixin):
  queryset = Despacho.objects.all()
  serializer_class = DespachoSerializer()
```

urls.py =>

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import *

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^despacho/<int:pk>', DespachoDetail, basename='despacho-detail')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: thank you, a really confused with this.